# Two Dimensional Array of a character and string function in C

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, implicit-conversion, c-strings

I am writing a C program which inputs string from a user sorts it alphabetical Order.
I have two questions here.

When I input the strings from user in this way below no  error occurs.

```
for(int i =0; i < 7; i++)
{
    printf("Enter the name %d\n",i+1);
    scanf("%s",&name[i][0]);
}
```

what does name[i][0] mean if

```
    char name[7][10];
```

Why are we setting up the 2nd index here to 0 ,isn't the 2nd dimension the maximum length of string which  our arrray can handle.

My second question is
For such type of array what does the string handling function takes `&name[i][0]` or `&name[i]`?

The code I have written so far gives me desired output however with lots of warning

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main() {
  char name[7][10];
  for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    printf("Enter the name %d\n", i + 1);
    scanf("%s", & name[i]);
    strlwr( & name[i]);
  }
  //Sort in alphabetical order
  for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < 7; j++) {
      if (strcmp( & name[i][0], & name[j][0]) > 0) {
        char temp[10];
        strcpy(temp, & name[i]);
        strcpy(name[i], & name[j]);
        strcpy(name[j], & temp);
      }
    }
  }
  printf("The names in alphabetical order is\n");
  for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    puts(name[i]);
  }
}
```

The warnings are:

```
 warning: passing argument 1 of 'strlwr' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
           98 |         strlwr(&name[i]);
```

and similar for other functions as well.

Comment: That's not a dimension, it's an index.

Comment: name[i] points to byte zero of the ith element of name, which is equivalent to name[i][0]

Comment: Numbers in square brackets are dimensions when you're declaring the array, they're indexes when you're using it.

Comment: The compiler should be issuing warnings for all of those...

Comment: @WeatherVane indeed it is

Comment: The **i**th string element is `name[i]`. So `strcmp( name[i], name[j])`. In this one `strcpy(name[i], & name[j]);` you are inconsistent: `strcpy(name[i], name[j]);`

Comment: `name[i]` is the `i`th string; `name[i][0]` is the first character in the `i`th string; `&name[i][0]` is the address of the first character in the `i`th string, and has the same value as `name[i]`.  The call to `strlwr()` (a non-standard function — as in, not in Standard C or POSIX) is passing a `char (*)[10]` to a function that expects a `char *`.  You need to call `strlwr(name[i]);`.  Both `scanf("%s", &name[i][0]);` and `scanf("%s", name[i]);` are valid and are equivalent.

Comment: @WeatherVane don't the string handling function takes the address of string and name[i] is a value ?

Comment: @IcanCode the array elements of the 2D array like `name[i]`, also decay to a pointer, in the same way that a 1-D array `temp` does.

Comment: @IcanCode: No; the string handling functions take a pointer to the first character of the string.  All of them — well, all of the standard ones, anyway.  `strlen(name[i])` would be correct; `strchr(name[i], 'A')` would be correct, `strcmp(name[i], name[i+1]) == 0` would be correct if `i` is not too large (or negative).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`names[i]` is an element of the array declared like

```
char name[7][10];
```

and has the type `char[10]`. That is elements of this two-dimensional array are one-dimensional arrays of the type `char[10]`.

Used in expression array designators (with rare exceptions as for example used as operands of the sizeof operator) are converted to pointers to their first elements.

So the expression `names[i]` used for example as an argument of the function `scanf` is converted to pointer to its first element. That is this expression is equivalent to `&names[i][0]`.

So instead of this call

```
scanf("%s",&name[i][0])
```

you could write

```
scanf("%s", name[i] )
```

The both expressions used as arguments have the type `char *`,

This call of scanf

```
scanf("%s", & name[i]);
```

has an argument of an incorrect type. The expression `&name[i]` has the type `char ( * )[10]` while the function expects an argument of the type  `char *` though the values of the both expressions are equal each other.

If you have an array declared like

```
char name[7][10];
```

then the values of these expressions

```
&name
&name[0] 
&name[0][0]
```

are equal each other and yields the address of the first byte of the memory extent occupied by the array.

However the types of the expressions are different. They are

```
char ( * )[7][10]
char ( * )[10]
char *
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char name[7][10];
    
    printf( "&name       = %p\n", ( void * )&name );
    printf( "&name[0]    = %p\n", ( void * )&name[0] );
    printf( "&name[0][0] = %p\n", ( void * )&name[0][0] );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
&name       = 0x7ffec1d18e40
&name[0]    = 0x7ffec1d18e40
&name[0][0] = 0x7ffec1d18e40
```

By the reason described above the arguments of these calls

```
    strcpy(temp, & name[i]);
    strcpy(name[i], & name[j]);
```

also have incorrect type `char ( * )[10]` while the function expects arguments of the type `char *`.

You need to write

```
    strcpy(temp, name[i]);
    strcpy(name[i], name[j]);
```

Comment: `The both expressions used as arguments have the type char *`  - not the truth. They have different types.

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland You are mistaken. The both have the type char * because as I wrote an array designator is converted to pointer to its first element.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow name[i] is pointer or  ith string?

Comment: @AbhilekhGautam In the answer of P__J supports women in Poland there is incorrectly written that it is a pointer. It is a wrong statement. It is an lvalue of the array type char[10]. For example if you write printf( "%zu\n", sizeof name[i] ); you will get the result 10. But the array designator used in expressions with rare exceptions as for example using in the operator sizeof is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element. . So the answer of P__J supports women in Poland is incorrect.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow then i can use strcpy(temp,&name[i][0]?did i get it correct

Comment: @IcanCode Yes it will be correct. The expression points to the first character of a string and has the type char *.